# Save Dashboards to a physical folder in Grafana

Tags: grafana

When I make changes to dashboards, Grafana DB gets updated with the updated dashboard; I would like to get these dashboards saved to a physical location alongside the db update; is this possible? I am asking this because it is easier to read a folder instead of querying the database.

Answer (score 0):

No (unless you will code that functionality on your own).

Grafana offers [Dashboard provisioning](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning/#dashboards), so it will load dashboards into Grafana from the local filesystem. In theory you may have all dashboards in the files, but you have to create/update them from the files first.